# Can I store unused hardwood floor and base trim in a shed (or garage)?

Tags: wood, hardwood-floor, humidity, storage

I have installed engineered hardwood all throughout my house, in addition wood base trim (which comes pre-primed). Now that my projects are done, I dont want to throw away the wood, incase I can use it for repairs or for a small future project, but its taking up space in my basement. Can I store the hardwood in my (non-climate controlled) shed, or will the varying weather/humidity render my wood useless for future projects?

I live in Maryland (winter hovers around 20 degrees f, and summers averaging around 90 degrees f) if that helps. The engineered wood is still boxed, the trim is not.

Comment: Can't say for sure how well it will hold up, but it will expand and contract in size due to temperatue and humidity differences.  Before using it however I would move it to a climate controlled setting a week ahead of time before you plan on using or installing it in the future.  This will give it time to acclimate and adjust.

Comment: Engineered floors typically have a 'max humidity' level that they tolerate, but I think that's based on it being installed. So, it may have no effect on flooring that hasn't been installed yet (aside from maple's valid point that regardless of where you store it, you need to acclimate it to the installation space prior to final installation).

Comment: Thank you, I understand the re-acclimating aspect of the flooring, I just wonder if the humidity could warp/distort the wood to such a point where it would render the hardwood/trim "uninstallable"

Comment: Asking the manufacturer would probably yield the best answer as they know their product and how it will respond

Comment: it could attract termites depending on the conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I store flooring in my shed/garage all the time. However, the humidity isn't very high where I live.

You should find out the  max humidty recommended by manufacturer and verify that it won't exceed that.

Also make sure not to store directly in contact with concrete floors as they could absorb moisture through the concrete.

For engineered flooring I would not be very concerned about warping/distortion if you store it flat and even.

You should be more concerned with adhesive breaking down, wood finish failing, and fungus/rot. All of which would most likely be cause by too high moisture content.

Answer (score 2):

To add to all the good things that have been said, assuming you do store it...

- Choose a well ventilated spot (as well ventilated as possible.)
- Keep it off the ground, or off a cement floor, if that would be in ground contact.
- Stack it flat, so there is no tendency to warp.
- If you stack it in piles, put stickers between the pieces in each stack, so that air can flow between them.

Do all of these things, and the growth of mildew/fungus/dry rot/warpage will be greatly retarded.